# Drupal 7 behaviors don't work

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-behaviors

I'm having a problem where Drupal behaviors seem to work with logged in users, but not everyone else, except when the behavior is executing a `submit()`.

For example this won't work.

```
Drupal.behaviors.login_activate = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $("#sr_login", context).hover(
      function(){
        $(this).append($("<span> ***</span>"));
      },
      function(){
        $(this).find("span:last").remove();
      }
    );
  }
};
```

This does work.

```
Drupal.behaviors.foundation_donation = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('#monthly_submit').click(function(){
      $('#monthly_donation').submit();
    });
    $('#single_submit').click(function(){
      $('#single_donation').submit();
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Just to get the obvious stuff out of the way: How are you adding these scripts for the page? You're sure they are being included for non-authenticated users?
And the attach event isn't firing at all? It's not just the subsequent jquery not working?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I think I figured out the problem after checking if the event was firing.  It is.  On this page http://dev.worldviewweekend.com/situation-room apparently none of the behaviors are working because of an error saying .once() in base.js is not a function.  However, on this page http://dev.worldviewweekend.com/tube which includes the same base.js file behaviors do work.  I can't figure out why the error is on one page and not the other.

Comment: The JS error seems to be killing Drupal behaviors.  I can't figure out why the error is present.  See previous comment for links and details.  Any help / guidance is greatly appreciated.